# Обработка дисков в разных потоках

Tags: vb.net, многопоточность

Как можно сделать, чтобы каждый диск обрабатывался в своём потоке?

```
    Sub list_of_file()
        For Each drive In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
            If drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Fixed Then
                seach(drive.Name)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Чтобы каждый `seach()` был в новом потоке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего запускать положить нужный код в метод и [вызывать его](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) в отдельном потоке

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf SomeMethod)
```

Comment: @Бегемот ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf seach(drive.Name))
так можно ?